# ASP.NET CORE with MySQL and EF Core - Multiple connection string handling

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have ASP.NET CORE 2 application with MySQL 5.7 and EF Core 2.0 in code-first approach.

I have setup my database in replication for Read and Write. So how can I configure my EF Core for these two connection string for respective operations i.e. Read and Write?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good choice to use open source DBMS with .Net core
first of all, install these two packages in your project:

1. Mysql.Data
2. Mysql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

You can do it simply from tools->Nuget packageManager -> package manager console

```
    install-package Mysql.Data
    install-package Mysql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
```

or install them to your solution(Manage NuGet packages for solution)

After that go to appsettings.json and add the  connection string as follow:

```
    {"ConnectionStrings": {
          "connectionName":"server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;database=mysqlTestDb;username=mysqlUser;password=mysqlPassword"},
```

Next, add your Context class and go to your startup.cs class for configuring mysql in DI in the ConfigureServices method add the following code

```
    string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("mysqlConnectionName");

    services.AddDbContext<DbContextName>(Options => Options.UseMySQL(connectionString));
```

After following all these steps, add migrations and update your database. I hope it works well for you.